# Assembly language question

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it okay to ask a question regarding a boot-loader program that has been written in x86 assembly language ?

Comment: I should note that since you're specifying the language it's written in, that it sounds like this is a bootloader you're programming. Not just one you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sounds like you want [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Generally, programming questions belong there.

The only exception I can think of is if you're really asking questions about how your boot loader should start a Unix kernel, e.g., which "command-line" arguments to pass to Linux.

If it goes beyond the knowledge a sysadmin would need to configure GRUB, LILO, etc., it probably doesn't belong here.

edit: You may want to review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the help center.

Comment: Would it be ontopic on http://serverfault.com/ ?

Comment: @Bernhard are you asking that, or suggesting it as additional clarification? If asking, no, it wouldn't be. If for clarification, I think Serverfault has a fairly different idea of on-topic vs. us. (Also, if asking, their meta would be the right place.)

Comment: I was just asking, because imho it was an option, but apparently not :)